# Oracle and TOAD (and I) disagree on number of variables to bind

Tags: oracle, variables, parameters, toad

At runtime, I'm getting "*ORA-01008 - not all variables bound*" with a SQL statement that runs fine in TOAD and in which TOAD (and I) only find one parameter.

As can be seen below, there IS only one parameter in the query. Why would Oracle think there are more than one parameters/variables and cause an exception to be thrown?

I cannot show the real sql, but here is a facsimile of it (column/table names changed):

```
SELECT DECODE(POSTWHEELTYPE,'0','NONE','D','NUMERIC','D','RESTRICTED NEEDLE','X','TRANSFER TO WINTER','A','ACCESS CODE') HALTYPE,      
    DECODE(VALIDATIONTYPE,'0','NONE','A','FOXPRO CODE','P','PERSONAL CODE','S','RESTRICTED') JBJTYPE,
    LAZYNUMBER,
    DISPLAYTEXT,
    MINLENGTH || '-' || MAXLENGTH LENGTH,
    NVL(INSTRUCTIONS, '<NONE>') INSTRUCTIONS
FROM
    ABC.CODELAZYS
WHERE
    BQSERVERABCID = :ABCID
    AND VALIDATIONTYPE <> '0'
ORDER BY
    LAZYNUMBER DESC
```

Comment: Is it possible that `:ABCID` isn't being bound, for some reason? Can you post the surrounding (non-SQL) code?

Comment: never mind - the problem was where I was binding my variable (too late); once I moved it above the call to ExecuteReader(), it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was binding the variable too late; once I moved it above the call to ExecuteReader(), it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If Oracle is returning this error code, I would bet the better part of my last dollar that the variable was not bound.  Just because TOAD has provided a value for the variable does not mean that it's bound in other clients.

Are you 100% positive your one variable is indeed bound? Where are you running the query that fails? Can you show us how it's called?

Comment: See my comment above - I would simply delete the post, but when I mash "Delete," all it offers to do is add a vote to delete it. It seems like the OP should be able to delete his own post at will...?

Comment: I think if you go ahead and vote to delete, it will delete the post - it only takes one owner vote to delete it. That's the way it works with answers, anyway.  That said, leaving this post intact might provide someone else a clue as to what they are doing wrong...